# Oracle - How to create a readonly user

Tags: oracle, readonly

It's possible create a readonly database user at an Oracle Database?
How?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A user in an Oracle database only has the privileges you grant.  So you can create a read-only user by simply not granting any other privileges.

When you create a user

```
CREATE USER ro_user
 IDENTIFIED BY ro_user
 DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
 TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```

the user doesn't even have permission to log in to the database.  You can grant that

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION to ro_user
```

and then you can go about granting whatever read privileges you want.  For example, if you want `RO_USER` to be able to query `SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME`, you would do something like

```
GRANT SELECT ON schema_name.table_name TO ro_user
```

Generally, you're better off creating a role, however, and granting the object privileges to the role so that you can then grant the role to different users.  Something like

Create the role

```
CREATE ROLE ro_role;
```

Grant the role SELECT access on every table in a particular schema

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM dba_tables WHERE owner='SCHEMA_NAME')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON schema_name.' || x.table_name || 
                                  ' TO ro_role';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

And then grant the role to the user

```
GRANT ro_role TO ro_user;
```

Comment: Ok it works, but only if the readonly user uses the schema_name. Is there a way the user can write the queries without schema_name?

Comment: Answer to my comment above: by using a private synonym.

Answer (score 22):

```
create user ro_role identified by ro_role;
grant create session, select any table, select any dictionary to ro_role;
```

Comment: Granting roles directly to tables is a nice indirection, but for simple use cases this is a much more direct answer. Also I find oracles "identified by" syntax confusing for new users, so I would use this:

`create user readonly_user identified by "password";
grant create session, select any table, select any dictionary to readonly_user;`

Answer (score 3):

Execute the following procedure for example as user system.

Set p_owner to the schema owner and p_readonly to the name of the readonly user.

```
create or replace
procedure createReadOnlyUser(p_owner in varchar2, p_readonly in varchar2) 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER is
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'create user '||p_readonly||' identified by '||p_readonly;
    execute immediate 'grant create session to '||p_readonly;
    execute immediate 'grant select any dictionary to '||p_readonly;
    execute immediate 'grant create synonym to '||p_readonly;

   FOR R IN (SELECT owner, object_name from all_objects where object_type in('TABLE', 'VIEW') and owner=p_owner) LOOP
      execute immediate 'grant select on '||p_owner||'.'||R.object_name||' to '||p_readonly;
   END LOOP;
   FOR R IN (SELECT owner, object_name from all_objects where object_type in('FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE') and owner=p_owner) LOOP
      execute immediate 'grant execute on '||p_owner||'.'||R.object_name||' to '||p_readonly;
   END LOOP;
   FOR R IN (SELECT owner, object_name FROM all_objects WHERE object_type in('TABLE', 'VIEW') and owner=p_owner) LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create synonym '||p_readonly||'.'||R.object_name||' for '||R.owner||'."'||R.object_name||'"';
   END LOOP;
   FOR R IN (SELECT owner, object_name from all_objects where object_type in('FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE') and owner=p_owner) LOOP
      execute immediate 'create synonym '||p_readonly||'.'||R.object_name||' for '||R.owner||'."'||R.object_name||'"';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create user and grant privilege

create user read_only identified by read_only;
grant create session,select any table to read_only;

Answer (score -1):

It is not strictly possible in default db due to the many public executes that each user gains automatically through public.