# ORA-00942 In grant select

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, sql-grant

I try to create a new Oracle user that it can only select from Tables (`ReadOnly`)

SO i had execute the next lines on `SYS` schema : (like [7502438](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502438/oracle-how-to-create-a-readonly-user))

1 - create user

```
CREATE USER my_user IDENTIFIED BY my_password DEFAULT TABLESPACE users  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```

2 - grant create session

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION to my_user;
```

3 - create a role

```
CREATE ROLE my_role;
```

4 - Grant select from an awner to the new role

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM dba_tables WHERE owner='OWNER')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON OWNER.' || x.table_name || 
                                  ' TO my_role';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

5 - grant the role to the user

```
GRANT my_role TO my_user;
```

So In the 4th part , i got this error

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 4
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So any ideas ?

Comment: 'OWNER' as schema name? i think it's little confusing

Comment: put dbms_output.putline(x.table_name) before EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, and you will see that table name

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there are dropped tables listed in the result of the DBA_TABLES query.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286

Comment: they all have  'valid' status

Comment: and their 'DROPPED' status?