# How to restrict Apache Zeppelin JDBC Interpreter to only select queries

Tags: jdbc, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I am doing POC for Apache Zeppelin for reporting purpose. I created a JDBC Interpreter to connect Oracle database. This way our user can execute queries and generate reports. Currently they have to login through toad to fetch data/report every day. We must restrict that.

But problem is, they can also execute update/delete queries. I want our user to run the **Select queries** and not any DML queries or Inserts.

Is there a way to restrict it? I expected some setting in configuration,
I tried to look on their documentation but couldn't find any clue.

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled in Oracle, rather than in your app? [Oracle - How to create a readonly user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502438/oracle-how-to-create-a-readonly-user).

Comment: yes, read only functional user on Oracle can be a last solution. But if this can be controlled on Zeppelin it shelf to handle error and all. Wondering if any hook script can be added to filter the query.

Comment: You need to handle DB access errors in your app anyway, regardless of where/how access permissions are enforced. (And I would not want some kind of filter in my application code to be the only barrier between the source data and potentially destructive inserts/updates/deletions.)

Comment: @AmitG, I am looking for a similar feature, are you able to restrict DML queries?

Comment: @kcoder, I couldn't find any other solution.  Then I choose to create a user on Oracle DB with READ_ONLY permission. and used that one in setup. This restricts update/delete.